# Yii "is not defined error" when updating a model property

Tags: yii, properties, model, runtime-error, yii-cactiverecord

Trying to wade my way through Yii here, learning on the fly.  We migrated a project off a unix server and on to a windows server and are experiencing some date/time difficulties.

I currently have a model "Activities" with a couple of properties `happend_on`, `happend_at`.  What I would like to do is set these properties to UTC time dynamically on the fly.  However I keep getting a Property `Activity.happend_on`, `Activity.happend_on` *is not defined error* from the CActiveRecord.php.  I read a couple of places about overriding the set methods in the model (didnt work) and at your peril, overriding the magic _set method, also didn't work. I really want to set these properties on the fly.

```
    $activity = $this->loadModel ( $id );
    $time = $activity->happened_on . " " . $activity->happened_at;
    date_default_timezone_set ( "UTC" );
    $utc_date = DateTime::createFromFormat (
        'm/d/Y H:i:s', gmdate ( "m/d/Y H:i:s", strtotime ( $time ) ), new DateTimeZone ( 'UTC' ));

    $date = $utc_date;
    $date->setTimeZone ( new DateTimeZone ( $time_zone ) );
    // THESE ARE THE LINES THAT FAIL - NEED TO UPDATE THE PROPERTIES.
    $activity->happend_on = $date->format("m/d/Y");
    $activity->happend_at = $date->format("H:i:s");
```

Comment: what means "on fly"? After loading model or before saving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You spelled `happend_on` and `happend_at` wrongly.

You meant to use `happened_on` and `happened_at` with an extra `e`.

This is very simple if you read the error message carefully, which is exactly what it says:
**The attributes could not be found because you misspelled them!**

Next time, if you get an *is not defined error*, check for the attributes mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Thanks man! Nice to have another set of eyes from time to time! Making me miss my IDE and all it does for ya!